# Dynamic adding and removing div elements using event streams (eventlistners)

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I has `div` block `feedList` which contains `feedItems`. Now to fill `feedList` with data (`feedItems`) i am using while loop. In future it will js which get data from backend dynamically.

I created 2 buttons, which is used to border num of `feedItems` in `feedList`. One is "5", another is "10". To border num of `feedItems` i use function which called on each event of adding `feedItem` `div` in `feedList`. You can see that this function check how much `feedItems` now in `feedList`: if it more than 5 - it remove old `feedItem` from `feedList`.

```js
var removeIf5 = function (event) {
    alert("last div removed if length more than 5");
};
var removeIf10 = function (event) {
    alert("last div removed if length more than 10");
};

document.getElementById("list5Items")
  .addEventListener("click" , function(e){
    alert("1");
    feedList.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf5, false);
    feedList.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf10, false);
    feedList.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf5, false);
});

document.getElementById("list10Items")
  .addEventListener("click" , function(e){
    alert("2");
    feedList.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf5, false);
    feedList.removeEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf10, false);
    feedList.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", removeIf10, false);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="feedField">
    <div class="feedNav">
        <div class="button-group-2">
            <input type="submit" id="list10Items" value="10"/>
            <input type="submit" id="list5Items" value="5"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feedList">
        <div class="feedItem">itemA</div>
        <div class="feedItem">itemB</div>
        <div class="feedItem">itemC</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem in that i create 2 functions for same work: they used to remove elements, and different only in border number. One remove if `feedList` length is more than 5, another - more than 10.

How i can rewrite my code?

Comment: When I click either button I see an error in the console: "_Uncaught ReferenceError: feedList is not defined_". Is the intention to reference the DOM element `<div class="feedList"></div>`? (which might work if the `id` attribute was set)

Comment: Honestly removing items from a list seems strange. Why not render a slice of the array? Also is the default behaviour to list all of the items?

Comment: @TedBrownlow, thats why i am asking that question: i got some solution, but thing that it's ugly. What about array? You suggest save all items in array and regular render just some of them (slice of array)? Default behaviour is to list items in realtime: when you got new item you render that one in DOM and remove unneeded old.